# Windows Sleep wakes in ubuntu

Tags: windows, sleep

Im new here, and im having an issue.

Im using Windows 7 sideloaded with Ubuntu.

The issue is, whenever i put my pc to sleep in the windows OS, it wakes up in ubuntu on the login screen. I dont know whats causing the issue, but I am not very happy about it haha.

Any tips or suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Sleep is not hibernate.  When you hibernate the system it has to boot back up normally at first, then load the saved hibernation image.  If you hibernate Windows and want to resume it, then when the system boots back up you have to choose Windows from the grub menu just like you did the first time, otherwise you'll boot Ubuntu instead.

Comment: Explaining that in common language, that means your Windows sleep is not working as sleep, but as hibernation, which is actually a reboot. You have 2 ways: either make Windows boot by default, or disable replacing sleep with hibernation. That can be done in Windows Control Panel, in Power section, advanced settings. There was something about hybrid sleep mode - disable it.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino, hybrid sleep means the system saves the hibernation image in case power is lost, but still goes to sleep, so if power is not lost, it just resumes from sleep.  Disabling it just means you lose your work should power be lost during sleep.